# Proof: Form of Subgroup Test

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have been told that this is a version of a Subgroup Test:

`If H is a non-empty subset of group G, H is a subgroup if:
     a. For any a,b in H there is a a*b in H
     b. There exists e in H such that a*e=e*a=a`

I have been trying to prove this; however, I can only come up with a proof which depends on H and G being finite. Has anyone seen this subgroup test before? What I wrote here as the definition, is it incomplete or wrong? Does anyone have a proof?

Comment: I believe you need $ab^{-1}\in H$.

Comment: As you found, when $H$ is finite, the presence of inverses can be deduced but otherwise (as shown in the Answer) it is false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This test is false.  Consider $G=(\mathbb{Z},+)$ and $H=(\mathbb{N}_0,+)$.  Since $H$ contains $e=0$, it satisfies both conditions, but is not a subgroup.

Comment: What if I gave the condition that the groups needed to be finite? ...

Comment: @RadekMartinez Then it is true. Prove it.

Comment: I have a proof for that. My defn was off